# How to change the default Jfrog Artifactory Dependency Declaration coordinate to Gradle format?

Tags: gradle, artifactory

We are using [Gradle build tool](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/) for almost all project in my company, but [[image]artifactory](/questions/tagged/artifactory) **Dependency Declaration** (as you see in he below screenshot) is defaulted to `Maven coordiate format`. Is there any way to change this in [[image]artifactory](/questions/tagged/artifactory) console to `Gradle coordinate format`?

[image]

> NB: We are using Artifactory Pro Power Pack 3.8.0

Answer (score 0):

Artifactory 4.0 and above just defaults to the repo your 'standing' on when clicking on [Set Me Up](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Using+Artifactory#UsingArtifactory-SetMeUp) -- There's no such functionality for lower versions.

[image: Set Me Up dialog]

Comment: does this feature allows to change Artifactories default Dependency decleration to Gradles coordindate?

Comment: No, but there's also not much need for default - it's dependent of which repo you currently have selected in the tree.

Could be a nice feature request though.